# Delete a table from NoSQL Workbench for local dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

I added two tables to my local dynamodb connection and couldn't seem to find a way to delete them. I would like to delete "CoreTable" and "CoreTable-local" as shown in the figure below. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the Operations drop-down.

[image: sample-image]

Answer (score 7):

I was able to use the aws-cli

`aws dynamodb delete-table --table-name <table name> --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`

to delete the table. But I still wonder if that can be done in NoSQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb has now added direct support for CreateTable, UpdateTable, and DeleteTable since Jun 2022 release. Upgrade your Nosql workbench to get this feature.

Visit [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/06/amazon-nosql-workbench-dynamodb-createtable-updatetable-deletetable-operations/)